# Execution thread and controlling number of these threads

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, thread-safety

first of all you should know that I am using spring-boot. I have some request such that it must be executed **synchronously** and it may take `10` seconds.  I know that for each request spring creates new thread. So it is ok for me.

Here, I explained why I need **synchronously** execute method.  I am not sure if it is neccessary, but I think that it is neccessary.

Moreover, I would like to control number of these thread, I am going to do something like that:

```
@Controller
class SomeContoller {
    @Synchronized
    int threadsCnt = 0;
    final int LIMIT = 10;     

    @PostMappin(...) 
    void someFunction() {
       if (threadsCnt >= LIMIT) {
          throw new LimitExceeded(...);
       }
       threadsCnt++;
       execute synchronously method ~ 10 s.
       threadCnt--;
}
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: If my appraoch is ok for this problem ?

Comment: I am not a spring expert. I would be wondering how the framework reacts to those exceptions you are throwing ... sounds like a strange idea to me.

Comment: Your understanding is flawed, spring isn't creating threads, those threads are created and managed by the servlet container. Spring has nothing to do with that. If you want to control the amount of threads create a task executor, then submit the task and use the returned future to wait for the result. Depending on your configuration that will hold other threads, queue them etc. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, the JDK and Spring already have solutions for that.

Comment: @M.Deinum could you answer for my question in more precise way ?  I think somethine like example ?

Comment: To control the number of thread, you probably need to design first how many you want, your execution policy and so on... Then you might want to have a look to ExecutorService